# Expo SDK 50 and expo-router 3 upgrade: node_modules/expo-router/entry.js: .plugins[0][0] must be a string, object, function

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

After upgrading expo and expo-router to latest I am getting this error : `node_modules/expo-router/entry.js: .plugins[0][0] must be a string, object, function`

I followed all the breaking change fixes in Evan's medium article ([here](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-router-v3-beta-is-now-available-eab52baf1e3e)) on expo-router v3 release.

I am not able to share much code; if you have any thoughts and would like a snippet of something specific I can possibly provide that, but has anyone come across this error yet? Not seeing anything in the GH issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm also encountering this problem when upgrading from expo sdk 49 to 50 and expo-router from v2 to v3.

My error is a bit different, but it looks like the same problem. I've checked my whole project stating plugins but nothing looks strange. I can't figure out what causes this error.

`error: node_modules/expo-router/entry.js: .plugins[0] must be a string, object, function`

Comment: Sorry you're having this problem too, but I am glad to know I'm not alone. I have a discussion thread in the expo repo: https://github.com/expo/expo/discussions/26642. 
I also seem to be the only person posting about this. I haven't been able to find anything of use in the issues or SO